# Apache: client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am getting

> [Tue Apr 24 12:12:55 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /labs/Projects/Nebula/bin/

My directory structure looks like (I am using Symfony 2, should be similar structure for other web frameworks)

[image]

I have vhosts setup like:

```
<VirtualHost nebula:80>
    DocumentRoot "/labs/Projects/Nebula/web/"
    ServerName nebula
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/nebula-errors.log"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/labs/Projects/Nebula/">
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0 192.168.1 ::1 localhost
</Directory>
```

I wonder whats the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: @JiewMeng: You should probably accept Phil's answer. It seems to be the problem with _most_ Apache installs today (Apache 2.4). Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK I am using the wrong syntax, I should be using

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
...
```

Comment: For apache > 2.4 this alone could not working for me. But it worked when combined with `Require all granted`, as suggested by @Phil-L

Answer (score 402):

Apache 2.4.3 (or maybe slightly earlier) added a new security feature that often results in this error. You would also see a log message of the form "client denied by server configuration". The feature is requiring an authorized user identity to access a directory. It is turned on by DEFAULT in the httpd.conf that ships with Apache. You can see the enabling of the feature with the directive

```
Require all denied
```

This basically says to deny access to all users. To fix this problem, either remove the denied directive (or much better) add the following directive to the directories you want to grant access to:

```
Require all granted
```

as in

```
<Directory "your directory here">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: might also need to add `Satisfy Any` after the `Require all granted`

Comment: @MarkHu - can you explain the possible necessity of `Satisfy any` in this context? I'm asking because I was pulling my hair out here, and adding this it got everything working for me. The odd thing is the app was working with the existing vhost entry until a recent Apache upgrade to `2.4.9`. Weirder again, is that it's working fine on another server with same app/vhost and Apache/PHP versions. Different servers though - AWS Linux and Ubuntu 14.10 respectively. Strange... I guess I need to compare each server's `httpd.conf` files to see if there is a config difference there...

Comment: Also check your `htaccess` at the path you are trying to access

Comment: My environment was not working until I decided to go with the @MarkHu Satisfy Any solution. Thanks!!!

Comment: even after changing to require all granted it is showing same error Access Denied.

Answer (score 5):

In Apache 2.4 the old access authorisation syntax has been deprecated and replaced by a new system using **Require**.

What you want then is something like the following:

```
<Directory "/labs/Projects/Nebula/">
  Options All
  AllowOverride All
  <RequireAny>
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

This will allow connections that originate *either* from the local host *or* from ip addresses that start with "192.168.1".

There is also a new module available that makes Apache 2.4 recognise the old syntax if you don't want to update your configuration right away:

```
sudo a2enmod access_compat
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue using Vesta CP and for me, the trick was remove .htaccess and try to access to any file again.

That resulted on regeneration of .htaccess file and then I was able to access to my files.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing "Allow from 127.0.0 192.168.1 ::1 localhost" to "Allow from all".
If that fixes your problem, you need to be less restrict about where content can be requested from

Answer (score 1):

Here's my symfony 1.4 virtual host file on debian, which works fine.

```
  <Directory /var/www/sf_project/web/>
    Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks    
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```

If you wan't to restrict access to a specific ip range, e.g. localhost use this:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
```

The [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html) is responsible for filtering ip ranges. You can look up detailed things in there.

But maybe the problem could be related to some kind of misconfiguration in your "apache2.conf".

On what OS is the apache running?

Answer (score 1):

if you are having the

```
Allow from All
```

in httpd.conf then make sure us have

> index.php

like in the below line in httpd.conf

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the key was:

```
AllowOverride All
```

in vhost definition.
I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -4):

This code worked for me..

```
 <Location />
Allow from all
Order Deny,Allow
</Location>
```

Hope this helps others

Comment: This should absolutely not be encouraged to add into an apache configuration.

Comment: This allows apache to access every file on the computer. Very bad for security.