# 403 Forbidden Directory access is forbidden - PHP Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown o n line 0

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm new to this. 
We did a system scan last night. However, during the scanning, the system is down and we are facing 403 forbidden error when access the web.

Please kindly assist how and where should i check.

Version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Ubuntu 4.2

The application was working fine all these while and no changes was done on the server.

YOur help on this is much appreciated.

thank you!

Here's the config file for further help:

```
/etc/apache2/apache.conf
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
#       Require all denied
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>  


/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

<Directory "/var/www/html">
   Options All
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Could you provide more information, like e.g. the error log entries? Than it'd be easier to solve the issue. Maybe you have to set the rights on some folders with chmod, but error log should help to find out where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Thanks.  [Sat Sep 06 00:11:35.581737 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 6091] [client X.X.
X.X:51144] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/temp
lates/_system/common_js/index.php
[Sat Sep 06 00:53:53.654579 2014] [:error] [pid 6089] [client X.X.X.X:531
47] PHP Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown o
n line 0

Comment: These are the repeated error found from error log. Any one has clues on this?

Comment: Ok. Would be good if you update this in the question so it's easier for anyone to get this information without reading the comments. Looks like you have to check what's in the conf-files - if you're unsure about that you should check e.g. the answers given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445686/ubuntu-server-apache-2-4-6-client-denied-by-server-configuration-php-fpm  as it's a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, Still no luck for me after following the steps.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to locate the problem without knowing the conf-files; though you already checked that, you may consider to add them in your question. Also provide information about the steps you've already taken (and btw just to be sure - in case you edit something in the conf, it might be necessary to restart the server so changes take place).

Comment: Thank you so much of your advise, but i've even tried to restart the server. Don't mind can share with me what are other config file i should include? I'm sorry, as i'm still new to ubuntu. As this server was working fine previously.

Answer (score 0):

As you already added some conf-files to your question and extended comments should be avoided on SO (and you don't have the required 20 reputation for moving to chat) next suggestions here: add also your .htaccess, and maybe this is of help: [Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration)
In addition, it might be of help if you open (depending on your browser and development tools) e.g. the Firebug Net Panel to check what happens when you call your site's url - if the 403 occurs directly or if there is any kind of redirect taking place. Could also be of help to trace the address in a shell / command prompt to see what's going on.