# Redmine CSS file access forbidden upon installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, redmine, ubuntu-14.04

I have just installed Redmine(2.5.2) on Ubuntu 14.04.
I am using Apache2+Passenger

The site works fine but it does not load css files like the following screenshot.
[image: No CSS Screenshot]

When I inspect, this is what I get.
[image: CSS Forbidden Error]

My VirtualHost is shown below.

> ServerAdmin admin@example.com
>       ServerName redmine.example.com
>
> ```
> DocumentRoot /usr/local/redmine/public
> RailsEnv production
> RailsBaseURI / <Directory /usr/local/redmine/public>
> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> AllowOverride All </Directory>
>
> ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/redmine.example.com-error.log </VirtualHost>
> ```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this problem?
Than you!!!

**Update**
This is apache error log

```
[Mon Sep 22 09:00:58.736635 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 20338] [client 175.130.114.60:56351] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/local/redmine/public/stylesheets/application.css
```

I don't see any error in redmine/log/production.log

Comment: Do you get any error messages in 'logs/production.log'?

Comment: This is what I see in the log file.                           Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Creating scope :system. Overwriting existing method Enumeration.system.
Creating scope :sorted. Overwriting existing method Group.sorted.
Creating scope :sorted. Overwriting existing method User.sorted.
Started GET "/" for 106.169.170.134 at 2014-09-22 01:24:32 -0400
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Current user: anonymous
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (103.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 373.7ms (Views: 139.8ms | ActiveRecord: 14.4ms)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this.
I got an answer from this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445686/ubuntu-server-apache-2-4-6-client-denied-by-server-configuration-php-fpm)
The issue lied with my VirtualHost configuratoin

I added the following line

```
Require all granted
```