# apache - error 400 in domain Debian 8

Tags: apache, dns, debian, virtualhost

I have a problem with apache 2.4 in debian 8. I am using virtualhosts in apache with fake domains (example.42). What happens is that when I do the example.42.conf file and I enable it to a2ensite example.42, when I enter the browser I miss an error 400: Bad request, do you know why it will be?

The domain is pointed correctly to the apache (I already made pings and everything well). There are people who tell me that it is apache problem, which is misconfigured virtualhosts. I already tried with all the settings and it does not remove the error.

The file virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName example.42 
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.42 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log 
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you try "**apachectl configtest**"?

Comment: Yes, and nothing

Comment: can you add your vhost here or apache log? :)

Comment: Ready, the virtualhost file

Comment: I dont see any error here. Please try clear cache, cookie, dns cache, restart apache. if not, read the error.log and apache log, i think here will have many useful infomation

Comment: I already tried to restart everything, clean cache and everything and it still comes out error. Where are the apache log files?

Comment: try this file /etc/apache2/error.log or /var/log then find there

Comment: In the error.log say **[authz_core:error] : client denied by server configuration /var/www/html/** and the other_vhosts_access.log say **example.42:80 192.168.0.19 - - [date] HEAD / HTTP/1.1 400 0 "-" "curl/7.38.0"**

Comment: Try add this block to vhost config

  <Directory />      Options All      AllowOverride All     Require all granted     </Directory>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445686/apache-2-4-6-on-ubuntu-server-client-denied-by-server-configuration-php-fpm

Comment: But with IP is fine, with domain don't work, say error 400

Comment: Did you add this line "Require all granted" to vhost?

Comment: yes, and don't work, say error 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the domain ".42", because apache has http header settings and the ".42" domain is invalid to verify https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html (CVE-2016-8743)

Possible solution (not recommended for sysadmin):
Changing the **HttpProtocolOptions Strict** variable by **HttpProtocolOptions Unsafe**

Check: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#HttpProtocolOptions