# Datapusher: Upload error:

Tags: ckan

I installed `CKAN Database (2.7.3)` from source on my `Ubunutu 16.04`.

I would like to ask for your help since I've encountered this error in `Datapusher`. I installed Datapusher through this guide

`http://docs.ckan.org/projects/datapusher/en/latest/`

and tried to run it. I've done the `development` and Prod`u`ction installation.
In the Resources, `"Datastore"` tab appeared but when I clicked upload, this error appears,

Upload error:

> An Error occurred while sending the job: 403 Client Error: Forbidden
>   for url: http://0.0.0.0:8800/job

Do you know how to fix it? Or the error behind this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In short, copy the following into your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/datapusher.conf` configuration file and then restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`.

**Code to Copy to `datdapusher.conf`**:

```
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

More on this can be found in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351167/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration/13923526#13923526) and this [ckan-dev discussion](https://lists.okfn.org/pipermail/ckan-dev/2014-June/007669.html).  This is actually in the `ckan_default.conf` configuration file that is generated when installing CKAN but for some reason not included or mentioned in DataPusher.

Comment: The code was in the datapusher.conf, and ckan_default.conf even before but still didn't work.